# Remove "G" from linear colorAxis in highmaps

Tags: highmaps

Does anyone know how to remove the "G" on my color Axis numeric labels? I've tried numerous things, including attempting to override/disable the "numericSymbols" in the highmaps.js src file and no luck. Also tried logarithmic, but the symbols get weird also. Seems like it should be an easy fix. Thanks for any help.

```
legend: {
          title: {
            text: '$ value in billions'}
          ,

          numericSymbols: {enabled: false},

          layout: 'horizontal',

          //labels: {enabled: false},
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'bottom',
          float: 'center'
         // valueSuffix: 'B',
          //margin: 50
        }
        ,
        mapNavigation: {
          enabled: true,
          buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            align: 'left'
          }
        }
        ,
        colorAxis: {
          min: 0,
          minColor: '#ffffff',
          maxColor: '#0c234b',
            labels: {enabled: false}

        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/drupalStarlord/ne3a2d99/1/

Comment: What "G" am I looking for? Can't see any in Chrome.

Comment: I can't see any "G" either, can you please give more details?

Comment: The "G" is after each number in the color axis labels below the map. I'm trying to remove them or change to "B"

Answer (score 0):

The G is short for giga, denoting a factor of a billion.

You can either create a custom formatter for the `colorAxis` labels, for example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ne3a2d99/3/)):

```
colorAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return this.value/1000000000 + "B";
        }
    }
}
```

This will not adapt if the values should suddenly be in a much smaller or larger range, unless you add some more depth to the code.

Or you could change the default `numericSymbols` metric prefixes, for example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ne3a2d99/2/)):

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        numericSymbols: ['.', '..', 'B', '....', '.....', '......']
        // Default is:  ['k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E']
    }
});
```

Here you'd have to find a suitable letter for each one if you expect the value range to vary.